# Smack xmpp - Establishing a Connection

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I just followed the getting started codes of Smack Xmpp 4.2.4 and I encountered this error. I was able to import the jar files needed. Can anyone help me? Here are the errors.

*The type org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The method setXmppDomain(String) from the type ConnectionConfiguration.Builder refers to the missing type XmppStringprepException*

Getting started code that I followed

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
      .setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password")
      .setXmppDomain("192.168.0.1")
      .setPort("5222")
      .build();

    AbstractXMPPConnection con = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    con.connect().login();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the jxmpp-core, jxmpp-util-cache,jxmpp-jid JAR files into your project.
[JXMPP Github](https://github.com/igniterealtime/jxmpp)
You may have other issues later, better read [Smack4.2 Readme](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide).